# How to gain information about a function inside a decorator with python?

Tags: python, inspect

Using a python decorator as follows

```
def decoratorFunctionWithArguments(msg):  
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            print ...
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap
```

I want to print out the following attributes of the function `f`:

- Name of the function
- Name of the module this function was called.
- Line of the module this function was called

I probably need the `inspect` module, but I am not quite sure how to use what method to achieve my goal. Or maybe I need to evaluate a traceback object?

Comment: What do you mean by "attributes given to this function"?

Comment: I removed this line - I meant every `*args` and all `**kwargs` given to the original function. But I have these already...

Comment: `f.__name__` contains the name of the function.

Answer (score 3):

This information can be retrieved in CPython with sys._getframe:

```
import sys

def mywrapper(msg):
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            f_back = sys._getframe().f_back
            print f.__name__, f_back.f_code.co_filename, f_back.f_lineno
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap

@mywrapper("message")
def f(x):
    return x*x

f(3)
```

This will output the name of the function and the module and line number from where it is called.